# link exe with //MT flag

Tags: windows, linker, rust, rust-cargo

I want to build exe file on windows,
without need of vcruntime.

So I tried:

```
.cargo/config
[target.i686-pc-windows-msvc]
rustflags = ["-Clink-args=/MT"]
```

looks like cargo found config, because of `cargo` rebuild
whole project, but `dumpbin /DEPENDENTS test.exe`
still show `VCRUNTIME140.dll` as dependencies,
any ideas how link `VCRUNTIME140` statically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [rfc](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1721-crt-static.md)

You can try it with rustc nightly:

```
c:\Users\IEUser\test2>rustc -Z unstable-options -C target-feature=+crt-static test.rs
```

Answer (score 0):

user1034749 answer pertains to rustc. If you want to do this with cargo, the info is here: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1721-crt-static.md

```
RUSTFLAGS='-C target-feature=+crt-static' cargo build --target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
```